# How do I prevent all terminals crashing in Mac OS Sierra?

Tags: mac, ssh, terminal, crash, gnu-screen

I usually have multiple terminal windows open, with most of them either ssh'ed into an Ubuntu session or running emacs.

In one of the ssh sessions, I was reattaching a screen (the screen was running code that produced some text output), and this caused all of my terminals to crash. This has happened multiple times, and I am wondering if this can be avoided, and if not, if there is a general terminal program for Mac OS that will either not crash or runs as completely independent processes, so one crashing will not cause the others to crash.

Comment: can you be more specific of what you are actually running inside the screen session to cause the crash - i can't even reproduce something that gives me a equal Result. To test if it is your Terminal.app that could be buggy you can try out iTerm2 https://www.iterm2.com - also instead of using screen you could try using tmux instead

Comment: I've got the same issue: ssh + screen on remote host => terminal crashing repeatedly